# Javascript not add class to label

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Can someone advise me why is this happening? Check image for info ... So..
I have to labels with same for and class value... first was created by form plugin and second one was created manualy in code block. And CSS works only for second one.

this created manualy:

```
<label for="forminator-field-radio-1-1-60f2d973cab35" class="forminator-radio">text
```

with this CSS:

```
label.javaclass {
background-image: url(https://test.ffd.sk/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/interier-obuv_8_polic.png);
width: 200px;
height: 800px;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
display: flex;
font-size: 60px;}
```

and javascript:

```
 var element = document.querySelector("label[for=forminator-field-radio-1-1-60f2d973cab35]");
element.classList.add('javaclass');`
```

[image]

And Forminator plugin give me same label what i put in code block. And script add class only in codeblock label but no in plugin label.

website:
[enter link description here](https://test.ffd.sk/java/)

Comment: try wrapping your element-alerting-init-code in a window.onload event listener

Comment: You are selecting only one element by using querySelector. Did you mean to select both, which  would be by using querySeectorAll.

Comment: also `src.appendChild(img);` is before the `document.getElementById("shortcode-30-453");` exists

Comment: @AHaworth if i change querySelector to querySelectorAll Wordpress hit me with error "TypeError: elementList in undefined"

Comment: How are you accessing the collection?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe there is multiple "label" tag in the page.
You Should use

```
element[0].classList.add('javaclass');`
```

Let me know if it doesn't work with your code!
Thanks

Comment: No reasonable answer should start with "maybe"

Comment: `querySelector` always returns one or none element.